# Using Rails update_all method to update fields with value from another column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to update a field in using update_all. However I need the value to be taken from another field which is re-written to my specific format.

If I have something like this in my model:

```
 def self.clean_mac_address()
   clean_mac_address = :macaddress.gsub(/[^0-9a-z]/i, '')
 end
```

When I run this:

```
 Radacct.update_all("mac_clean = #{clean_mac_address}")
```

I get an error:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `gsub' for :macaddress:Symbol
```

Any thoughts how I can do this? Or is there a simpler way to update the field?

Comment: I doubt if you can use `gsub` method on a `symbol`. May be thats the reason you are getting error.

Comment: First, why are you calling `gsub` on a symbol? Second, if I understand correctly you want to calculate and fill `mac_clean` column based on other column for every record. In that case you can use `update_all` only if you perform all manipulation in SQL as `update_all` will run the update you're passing to it as a string on all records, but it won't load them from DB and won't initialize model instances. That means you're dealing with SQL queries and do not have direct access to `ActiveRecord` attributes.

Comment: @KL7 :macaddress isn't supposed to be a symbol - it should be a string. So, I have to write something to loop through each record and update?? Am a bit confused.

Comment: Main difference between a symbol and string is that symbol is unique and immutable. We generally use symbol to represent something, eg: as the key of a hash in parameters `params[:id]`. What is :macaddress in above code?

Comment: It's actually sent to db by our radius server and is a record of which locations our customers are calling in from. Because it has the wrong format, I need to rewrite it but determined this would be better at authentication time. Therefore, all new sessions have this field entered in correct format. However, I'm left with several thousand fields with no value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`update_all` generates a single SQL query to run - it can't do clever stuff like change arbitrary bits of ruby into equivalent SQL.

You either need to load all you instances (via `find_each` for example) and fix them one by one (ie don't use update_all), for example

```
Foo.find_each do |foo|
  # update foo here
  foo.save!
end
```

Or find a way of expressing that cleaning operation in SQL. For example Postgres has a `regexp_replace` function

```
Foo.update_all("some_column = regexp_replace(some_column, 'your_regexp_here', '','g')")
```

Which would remove everything replacing that regexp. Obviously you'll need to check the documentation for your database to see whether it supports such a feature.

Comment: Do I need to stick this in a loop to find record A, replace value, move on etc. etc?? Can you share some code? S

Comment: Depends on which of the 2 ways I suggested you choose

Comment: Ok, ill look into it. Am on mysql. S

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times. Every time I have to write a batch update I end up googling for this method name.

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer provides a nice way to `update_all`, what I'd use is

```
read_with_clean_addr = Radacct.where(mac_clean: :macaddress.gsub(/[^0-9a-z]/i, ''))
read_with_clean_add.update_all(mac_clean: "#{clean_mac_address}")
```